# Converting from DOUBLE (15,2) to DECIMAL (15,2)

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

Will there be any data loss when converting between double and decimal in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubles have ~16 decimal digits of precision.  So the answer is no, since both types are declared to have 15 decimal digits of precision.  (If the types had 16 digits, it would depend on the number stored since the precision of doubles is actually between 15 and 16 digits.)

Answer (score 0):

> The maximum number of digits for DECIMAL is 65 (64 from MySQL 5.0.3 to 5.0.5). Before MySQL 5.0.3, the maximum range of DECIMAL values is the same as for DOUBLE, but the actual range for a given DECIMAL column can be constrained by the precision or scale for a given column. <sup>[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)</sup>

I would guess no.

Answer (score 0):

A DOUBLE-precision floating-point number is accurate to approximately 15 decimal places. DECIMAL has a precision of 65 digits. You wouldn't lose any data when converting from DOUBLE to DECIMAL. As Brad says, previously the maximum range of DECIMAL values were the same as for DOUBLE. [Numeric Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

If you are doing numeric computations on your data and need more that 15 decimal places, I would suggest you take the time and convert your columns to DECIMAL since DOUBLE stores an approximation of the value and not the actual value.

Comment: exactly why I am converting to decimal