# Changing over from double data type to decimal

Tags: mysql, double, decimal, type-conversion

I have a database that currently uses the `double` data type and I want to change it to using the `deciaml` data type as I heard the `double` data type can't really be trusted when storing monetary data as it's approximate.

So I'm just wondering if I should expect any issues if I just change the data type? Everything should change ok with no loss of data?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962078/converting-from-double-15-2-to-decimal-15-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do have a risk of losing data unless planned carefully, but as long as you ensure that your data is already consistent and you choose correct length for the field you should be fine. Consider the following:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY COLUMN yourcolumn DECIMAL;
```

This will convert `yourcolumn` into `DECIMAL` but it'll result in DECIMAL(10,0) which is practically integer column. If you go ahead and convert to DECIMAL(10,2) instead:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY COLUMN yourcolumn DECIMAL(10,2);
```

You will lose everything beyond 2nd decimal. As an example value 10.025 will be converted to 10.03. If all your values already have only two decimal positions you should be fine.

All above holds for MySQL 5.5.25

Comment: Ok, so as long as I create the new column with the same details such as `(10,2)` or what have you it should be fine?

Comment: Yes. Know your data and make sure your precision matches or exceeds your data requirement. @AbhikChakraborty's method of creating additional column with new data type and then verifying the conversion is very good approach - it'll help you catch possible rounding errors.

Comment: Second statement produces this error in my case: `Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'my_column' at row 1`.

Answer (score 1):

One safe way to do is as

```
alter table your_table add column `test_col` decimal(8,2);
```

Then copy the existing values to the new col as

```
update table `your_table` set test_col = `col_double_datatype`;
```

Then check if the data is copied properly and if looks good drop the `col_double_datatype` and rename the `test_col` to the one you are using.

Comment: He specifically asked for issues (if any)

Comment: There are always issues when you convert any existing datatype to a new one, so its better to do safe conversion instead of doing literal conversion, so that in case of mishap your data is intact.

Comment: If we are talking about safety then simply just make a backup before change something.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me on MySQL 8.
My solution (with a `decimal(14, 4)` field):

```
UPDATE your_table SET test_col = cast((col_double_datatype * 1000000 / 1000000) as decimal(14, 4));
```