# Laravel reduce amount of decimal places

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an API endpoint that points to `/api/invoices` and it returns a list of invoices.

Some invoices return something like this:

```
{
    "id": 2555,
    "entity_id": 88,
    "net_total": 7.5,
    "total_vat": 1.725000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625,
    "grand_total": 9.2249999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375,
}
```

As you can see, there's too many decimal places. My money columns are all defined as `double(20,5)`, because the software needs to handle up to 5 decimal places (but mostly is only 2) and 20 units.

Is there any way to force either through MySQL or Laravel, to always return 5 decimal places? **I can't use**:

```
->selectRaw('ROUND(total_vat, 5) as total_vat')
```

Because I have around 100 columns and I get them all without using `->select()`.

Comment: What happens when you use [DECIMAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/fixed-point-types.html) instead of DOUBLE?

Comment: @BillKarwin hmm, nice suggestion. I have implemented and the result comes with only 5 decimals, but I have two questions: 
1. My software is in production and I have more than 200k rows, is there any problem changing from DOUBLE to DECIMAL?
2. The output, in Laravel / Postman, shows as string (with double quotes) "1.72500" instead of number, is it normal?

Comment: You can define the scale of a DECIMAL. I usually use `DECIMAL(9,2)` for currency. In some financial applications, it's standard to use 4 digits of scale, so that would be `DECIMAL(11,4)`. You should test carefully — and not on your production data — to satisfy yourself that the conversion happens as you expect. Don't trust what some stranger on the internet says, and back up your data first.

Comment: You should also read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/problems-with-float.html and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. You've been a programmer for years according to your profile. This information should not be new to you.

Comment: If you are consider changing your column type, you might also want to consider storing cent value in an int type column. And honestly that might relieve you from a lot of headaches that you are facing right now, and that's one way of addressing the floating point dilemma.

Comment: @BillKarwin I just saw this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24135191/3355243 where the guy  says that if the column matches the same details (20,5) it should be fine converting from `double` to `decimal`.

Comment: @user3532758 can't do that right now. The project is big, already in production and I have lots of currency columns. It would be a pain in the ass to create a cents column for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to convert the columns into decimals and maintain the same structure, like said in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/24135191/3355243.

I did a few tests and the column value kept the original data.

However, this will lead to another issue, which is laravel casting decimal as string. By using postman, we can see that currency values comes as string, like "15.00". To solve this we can use cast [Eloquent casts decimal as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288519/eloquent-casts-decimal-as-string):

```
protected $casts = 
[
    'net_total' => 'float',
];
```

I wasn't able to find / check if using the cast creates any problem with the original value.

**Be careful while converting** `DOUBLE` to `DECIMAL`, as, like in my case, this may trigger severe problems in your project. For example, my mobile App stopped working after the conversion, because is not ready to handle the currency values as string.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using API Resources for transforming data.

If you just return `Invoices::all()` in your API, then yes, it will return "as is".

But a typical way to transform any data would be [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources):

```
php artisan make:resource InvoiceResource
```

Then, inside of that resource, you return only what you need and transformed however you want, including the 5 digits:

**app/Http/Resources/InvoiceResource.php**:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'entity_id' => $this->entity_id,
        'net_total' => $this->net_total,
        'total_vat' => number_format($this->total_vat, 5),
        'grand_total' => number_format($this->grand_total, 5),
    ];
}
```

Then, in Controller:

```
public function index() {
    return InvoiceResource::collection(Invoice::all());
}
```

Also, API Resources would add "data" wrapper layer by default when returned, so you may want to avoid that, then add this to AppServiceProvider:

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
 
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        JsonResource::withoutWrapping();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of API Resource and I'm using it in recent projects, but this particular project I can't for several reasons. Thumbs up for the solution.